# What the generic name of named tuple in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wrote this code:

```
type SomeOptions = {
  a: string;
};

type SomeMethod<T extends any[]> = (
  ...args: [...T, otherOptions: SomeOptions]
) => void;
```

but the TypeScript checker throws the error: "Tuple members must all have names or all not have names."

So how can I define `T` as named tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
type SomeOptions = {
  a: string;
};

type SomeMethod<T extends any[]> = (
  ...args: [...pre: T, otherOptions: SomeOptions]
) => void;
```

or

```
type SomeOptions = {
  a: string;
};

type SomeMethod<T extends any[]> = (
  ...args: [...T, SomeOptions]
) => void;
```

Comment: Nope, I understood the error text correctly. I want all parameters to be named.